# SymmetricDS: Database System Design

Tags: symmetricds

[image: System Design]

I need some advices, I want to build the database system like this using SymmetricDS.

The Orange Box is a PC that sync 1 API Database and 1 APP Database.

The Grey Box is multiple-PC that sync each API Database.

The idea is I want to make the system can handle multiple APP, so I need create API Database that synced with other API Database. 
And also I need create APP Database that synced with local API Database independently (using transformation table and column).
So there is 2 SymmetricDS instances, 1 between each API System, and 1 between APP and API System.

Is that good to make separate 2 SymmetricDS instances? Or just 1 for all? Or is there other recommendation design?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one symmetricds instance can sync multiple databases. so, one instance per location. i.e., one symmetricds in the central hub, and one per local

Comment: so should I use 2 instances or just 1 for all?
Every API node need to configure independently

Comment: I suppose the system is distributed. If it's a case then one instance of symmetricds per location. If all DBs are collocates then one instance should do the job

Comment: thank you for advice, yes this system is distributed